# Rail gon gem & Turbolinks - where to place the

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm using gon and have in my app Turbolinks.

According to this [website](https://fullstacknotes.com/bring-rails-data-to-javascript-with-gon/), you should "Include Gon in body instead of head when using turbolinks to make Gon reload in each pave moving".

for the moment I have followed [gon page instructions](https://github.com/gazay/gon) and put it inside the <head>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>            
      <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
      <!-- gon on top of page -->
      <%= include_gon(:init => true) %>
        <%= Gon::Base.render_data({}) %>


    </head>

    <body>
     </body>
</html>
```

Is it relevant? what is "pave moving" ? in which case should I move gon code inside the <body> ?

Comment: looks like a typo.  pave maybe referring to page.  so try moving that code inside the body.

Comment: @jvnill i think you're right. I'll try.

Comment: well, i had the issue of gon data not being updated when using turbolinks, and your question helped me find the solution (moved include_gon to body and now it works...

Comment: @Israel Roth: same here. Thanks for this post!